# Issues setting up Kafka on localhost

Tags: apache-kafka

I ran into an issue while trying to set up kafaka (version 2.12-2.4.0) on my local machine by following:
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

I created a very simple spring-boot app that had a producer and consumer by following some online tutorials.  When I would start up my app it would spin for 30 seconds and then start throwing errors in the logs trying to create a topic with connection errors.

I thought maybe my spring-boot app was misconfigured so I tried creating a topic from the command line but I got a similar error:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testing

Error while executing topic command : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
[2020-02-11 21:57:06,545] ERROR java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:225)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:194)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic$(TopicCommand.scala:189)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:217)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:61)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Kafka and zookeeper were up and running but nothing could connect to kafka.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the kafka logs said it was listening on 0.0.0.0:9092:

```
INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
```

I went into the server.properties and changed all the localhost values to:

```
# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

This solved the problem.  I don't know if this is an issue with my laptop but I wanted to save other people time.  I didn't have to change my spring-boot connection configuration, connecting to localhost still worked.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is perfectly fine

Comment: To clarify, if `localhost` doesn't work, problem could be your /etc/hosts file

Comment: Explanation of what 0.0.0.0 means in this question https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Comment: Like I said in my answer, this might be an issue with my laptop.  It is a company laptop and they lock it down so maybe something is locked but the bottom line is it didn't work till I changed it to 127.0.0.1.  Thanks for the explanation of 0.0.0.0, that was helpful.